# ASP.NET 4.6 doesn't turn response in HTTP2 (azure website)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, http2

I've set my website to asp.net 4.6 runtime and the website was all ready only accessible in https so those two requirements are met. Also I visited the site with an HTTP2 supporting browser like Chrome or IE11. Also the website is hosted as a Microsoft Azure Website

I've used the following sites for reference
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/812 and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1127/aspnet-webforms-new-features

Unfortunately I can't share the website with you because it's a client's and I guess he doesn't like that.

My question to you is, has anyone already used HTTP2 on Azure and maybe have some tips or input for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Casper,

short answer should be "NO", it is not supported yet.

there is an old discussion in below link

https://superuser.com/questions/926663/iis-and-http-2-server-support

to check what OS Azure App Service is running, you can create a site, go to your debug console from scm site (https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole), and run "ver"

from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

NT 6.2 is Windows Server 2012

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what are the plans to support it? It looks like I am going to have to deploy to AWS instead.

Comment: Providing HTTP/2 for Azure Web Apps was requested last year, and according to MS, it has been "started," but they didn't give any timeline: "As our environment is quite large, it will take us a while to upgrade our boxes. We are not ready to announce a timeline yet." https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9552936-enable-http-2-on-azure-web-apps

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET 4.6 Runtime only supports HTTP/2 on Windows 10 using latest IIS and Windows 2016 IIS.  Doesn't add that capability to prior OS/IIS combos (I've tried).  I don't think Azure Websites yet supports HTTP/2, at least when I checked a few months back, probably not Windows 2016/newest IIS since Windows 2016 was still in Technical Preview last time I checked.  (Also I think due to browser support you need to use SSL for HTTP/2 connections...so would make sure trying over https for your azure site...)

Answer (score 0):

The Auzre App Service was recently (Jan 2018) upgraded to server 2016, and the team are [working on enabling HTTP/2 on the platform](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9552936-enable-http-2-on-azure-web-apps).

The latest status from the team on 16th March 2018 was:

> Hi all, thank you for your patience! We are getting through a few last items getting ready to release HTTP/2 support very soon. I'll be notifying here and our team blog once available. 
>   https://aka.ms/AppServiceBlog

A work around we're using for one of our sites (not on Azure, but still on an older version of IIS) is to use an HTTP/2 enabled CDN infront of the application.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP2 is now enabled in App Services, however it is off by default. It must be enabled in the App Service Settings:

[image]

Announcement post:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/